# Is setting state inside render function an ok solution?

Tags: react-native, render, setstate

I am seting state inside some components which are located inside render() and I am wondering if that is a good way to set state:

```
<TextInput style={{ fontSize: 14, marginLeft: 10, marginRight: 10, color: 'black', borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, textAlignVertical: 'top' }}
                    onChangeText={(txt) => this.setState({ waitReason: txt })}
                    autoFocus
                    multiline={true}
                    numberOfLines={3}
                    placeholderTextColor='gray'
                    placeholder='Comment'
                    value={this.state.waitReason} />
```

Or maybe calling a function and then seting the state inside that function could be a better solution?!

Comment: Calling a separate function might make the code a little more maintainable but I don't see a problem with your current approach. Does it work as expected?

Comment: @shennan it does work perfectly fine, but was wondering if that is making my app rerender unnecessarily or affecting the performance somehow

Comment: Re-renders on state change is one of the main goals of using React. So long as you're happy with React's performance overall, this approach should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that you're not setting state inside an actual render. You're rendering a component and setting state inside an event handler. So, in your code, a re-render is only enacted when the `onChangeText` handler is called, which is only when text changes.

Your approach should be fine. Separating out to a different function won't change the performance of the code, but may make it more maintainable.

Your approach is pretty-much used as an example in the [React Native documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-text-input) itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is okay to setState in render especially when dealing with user inputs. 
 
like in react-native [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-text-input)

Answer (score 0):

setState inside render has no issue but to maintain the standard code , functions should be used such as handleChange or on click functions are used when state need to be set on particular event.

Comment: in one case actually setting state inside the render() was being called in the begin when the app started, so I had to call a function first and set state inside that function instead.

Comment: yes in that is the case so you should setState most probably on function call or event handling so you can do it and prevent yourself settingState on app start.

Comment: I dont understand why is it called if I am not pressing in TouchableOpacity yet?